# Show that the estimator $\beta_1 = (X_1 + 3X_n + 4)/4$ is unbiased.

Tags: statistics

Suppose we are given an estimator $$\beta_1 = \frac{X_1 + 3X_n + 4}{4}$$ and the pdf given is $$f(x|\beta) = \frac{1}{\beta+1} e^{-\frac{x}{\beta+1}}.$$

and we have to show this is unbiased, i.e
$$\text{Bias} = E(\beta_1) - \beta=0.$$

What would the expected value of $\beta_1$ be?

Comment: Do you mean to have $X_n$? Also use `\beta` for $\beta$. Also, what do you think it should be? Also also, what kind of density does that look like? Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme No, we have not been given $X_n$

Comment: I meant, it is correct that you wrote $X_n$? You did not mean $X_2$ or something?

Comment: yeah, it's $X_n$.  I worked it out and got $\theta + 1 + 3\theta + 3 - 4$ = $4\theta$.  I don't know if that's correct.

Comment: You should always include your work in your post. Also, I think what you worked out is wrong. Can't tell since you have no details. Finally, $\theta$??

Comment: Why $+4$ in the definition of $\beta_1$ and $-4$ in your calculation?

Comment: So i found the expected value, $E[X_1] = ∫ x f(x|\beta) = \beta + 1$. Then $E[\beta_1] = E[X_n] + 3E[X_n] + 4$. when substituting in this, I get, $\frac{1}{4} [ \beta +1 +3\beta + 3 +4]$

@AndréNicolas I just saw my mistake about the sign, how do i do this?

Comment: One unbiased estimator of $\beta$, by a calculation you know how to do, is $\frac{X_1+3X_n-4}{4}$. Maybe that's what was intended, and there was a typo.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so my process was right? I find the expected value of X and just substitute it in $\beta_1$?

Comment: Yes, the process is right.  If you recognize the exponential distribution and remember its mean, you don't even have to integrate.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Alright Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume there are several typos. If you were ***told*** to show that this is unbaised, then I think the correct estimator is 
$$\beta_1 = \frac{X_1+3X_2-4}{4}.$$

As the question I asked suggests, we notice that the density given tells us that
$$X\sim \text{Exp}(1/(\beta+1)).$$
Hence, we have that
$$E[\beta_1] =E\left[\frac{X_1+3X_2-4}{4}\right] =\frac{1}{4}[(\beta+1)+3(\beta+1)-4] = \beta.$$
Thus
$$E[\beta_1] = \beta$$
so this estimator is unbiased.

Comment: I found this is an old exam paper, there might be a typo. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Comment: can i ask a quick follow up? To find the Sufficient Statistic for $f(x|\beta)$, we would take the Likelihood $L(\beta)$ but when we do how do you separate $\beta + 1$ to $\beta$?

Comment: I don't remember that. I can't even say that you are doing the right thing, and I don't have time to review it at the moment. Otherwise, I would help you. But feel free to post a new question, proving all the details and attempts you have made.

Comment: Alright, Thanks again